# Groovy Xml Holder returns 'null' as a value of existing attribute

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to parse the web-service response below:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <GetReservationRS>
            <Reservation>
                <PassengerReservation>
                    <Passengers>
                        <Passenger id="4">
                            <AncillaryServices>
                                <AncillaryService id="15">
                                    <RficSubcode>0AA</RficSubcode>
                                </AncillaryService>
                            </AncillaryServices>
                        </Passenger>
                    </Passengers>
                </PassengerReservation>
            </Reservation>
        </GetReservationRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

I need to get a value of 'id' attribute which is located in 'AncillaryService' tag. For this purpose I've composed the following XPath which works fine in XML Pathernizer plugin for Notepad++

```
//GetReservationRS/Reservation/PassengerReservation/Passengers/Passenger/AncillaryServices/AncillaryService[RficSubcode/text()='0AA']/@id
```

Also, I'd like to create a groovy script for this action. Please find a  script excerpt below:

```
String responseText = context["Get reservation EMD#Response"]
responseText = responseText.replaceAll("<[A-Za-z0-9]+:", "<").replaceAll("</[A-Za-z0-9]+:", "</");
def xmlHolder = new XmlHolder(responseText)
String aeBookedRficSubCode = "0AA"
String prepaidAirExtrasXpath = "//GetReservationRS/Reservation/PassengerReservation/Passengers/Passenger/AncillaryServices/AncillaryService[RficSubcode/text()='${aeBookedRficSubCode}']/@id"
String prepaidAirExtras = xmlHolder.getNodeValue("${prepaidAirExtrasXpath}")
log.info prepaidAirExtras
```

After a script execution I can see a 'null' caption in the log. So, my script extracts 'null' value from this XML. Do you have any ideas, how could I fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Obviously, inserting `${aeBookedRficSubCode}` does not work well. Try concatenating 1) the part before this variable with 2) the variable and 3) the part of the expression after this variable - instead of writing it as a single string.

Comment: You have `String aeBookedRficSubCode = "OAA"` With a capital `o`, instead of a zero `0`...

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. Value is taken from a parameter, which has '0AA' value. I've typed here this variable in order not to bring too many function calls here

Comment: Is that the _complete_ XML document you're querying or is there a SOAP envelope or similar wrapped around it?  It may be a namespace issue if there's a wrapper element that includes an `xmlns="..."` declaration.

Comment: Namespaces are removed before parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've investigated problem stated in the question above and it seems to me that it's XmlHolder's issue, because there are something about 50 namespaces descalred in SOAP-envelope header and XmlHolder can't parse it for unknown reason.

So, I've decided to refactor test script in  the way which uses XmlSlurper instead of XmlHolder

```
String aeBookedRficSubCode = context["#TestSuite#aeRficSubcode"]
String responseText = context["Get reservation EMD#Response"]
def reservationResponseNode = new  XmlSlurper().parseText(responseText).Body.GetReservationRS
def ancillaryServiceByTypeNode = reservationResponseNode.Reservation.PassengerReservation.Passengers.Passenger.AncillaryServices.'*'.find{node->
    node.name() == "AncillaryService" && node.@RficSubcode == aeBookedRficSubCode
}

String prepaidId = ancillaryServiceByTypeNode.@id

testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("aeBookedId", prepaidId)
log.info testRunner.getTestCase().testSuite.getPropertyValue("aeBookedId")
```

Answer (score 1):

From the supplied XML, the XPath that I would use is: `//*:AncillaryService/@id/text()`, which says:

- `//`: anywhere in the document
- `AncillaryService`: find this node; will pick the *first* if there are multiple
- `*:`: with any namespace
- `/@id`: select its "id" attribute
- `/text()`: select that attribute's text value; SoapUI assumes this if you do not specify

As for your Groovy script, I am not quite sure why you are making is so incredibly complicated. The following should do:

```
def prepaidAirExtras = context.expand( '${Get reservation EMD#Response#//*:AncillaryService/@id}' )
log.info prepaidAirExtras
```

Comment: Response includes namespaces which vary from build to build. That's why I need to remove namespaces from response before processing.

Comment: @Eugene The correct way to handle that is using wildcards `*:`.